# Marketo- next_page_token in Get Multiple Leads by Filter Type

Tags: marketo

How to use next_page_token in Get Multiple Leads by Filter Type?
If there is already a limit of 300 values per request, what is the place of the next_page_token input which is mentioned in the documentation?
http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-multiple-leads-by-filter-type/

In addition, I have noticed that when I send around 500 lead s to filter I receive a next page token in the response. When should I expect to receive a next page token in the response?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The next page token is return when the set of leads filtered is greater than the batch size of the call(which defaults to 300).  You can pass a subsequent call with the same filter and this next page token to return the additional records.